# Launching java as a service and specifying the user

Tags: java, ubuntu, service

As an introduction, let's just say I'm a real noob using linux. I try to do the things right, don't hit me if it's ugly.

So, the problematic. I'm trying to run some jars as webservices on an ubuntu server. I created a specific user (nuxservice) with no pwd. I edited sudoers to enable a few users (myself & root) to sudo using this account with no password.

I then took a lot of inspiration from : http://www.jcgonzalez.com/linux-java-service-wrapper-example

Most is working, only one real problem, my java process seems to not have the right to create its logging files.

I run my services with a classic

```
sudo service myservice start/stop/restart
```

The command line that are launching my services are :

```
nohup sudo -u nuxservice java -jar myjar.jar myargs
```

When I do a ps -ef, the services are launches with my nuxservice user.

When I do ls -ld, nuxservice is the owner and have the rights.

If I launch the command in a terminal myself, it works. When launching as a service, my logs files are not created.

Any clues mates ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So...

It was kinda silly.

My user rights were fine. Problem is, I did not set the working folder in my script so Java was all lost considering the creation of the folder/files for logging.

All I had to do was adding a little

```
cd $PATH_TO_JAR
```

And it was all set !